# if statements in an arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```js
storyWords.filter(word => if (unnecessaryWords.includes(word)){
  continue;
}
else{
  betterWords.push(word);
}) ;
```

I keep getting an error "Unexpected token if", I was wondering if when you use an arrow function the syntax for if statements is different than in a regular function.

Comment: You can't use a statement or declaration in a context where only an expression is allowed. Use an arrow function with `{}` so that you can put statements inside it.

Comment: Please read the [docs on the syntax of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax).

Comment: that's not how filter is used .. it should be `betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !( unnecessaryWords.includes(word) ));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) (break, continue, if...else or switch)  inside the arrow function you need to use curly braces: `{ }`.

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the explicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

So write:

```js
storyWords.filter(word => {

  if (unnecessaryWords.includes(word)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    betterWords.push(word);
  }

});
```

Comment: As you quoted the documentation yourself: In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement. Is the `continue` keyword valid outside any loop?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, I don't think it is valid outside loops, MDN reads: **The continue statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.**

Comment: The iteration is done in the `filter` method. In the context of the callback function there is no loop. `filter` expects a bool return value.